# Page auto jump top after reload in jqm

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile to create second page, In my second page, I have list of images. I have a js function to handle page load to bottom when the second page is created. When I click the second page, the page is scroll to bottom successful. But when page is finished load. the page jump to top itself. My js function as below:

```
function scrolltobottom() {
    var areachat = document.getElementById('indexbody');
    areachat .scrollTop = textareachat.scrollHeight;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("pagecreate", "#secondpg", function () {  
        setTimeout(scrolltobottom, 1000);
    });
});
```

My sample html code:

```
<html>
<body id="indexbody">
   <div data-role="page" id="homepg" data-url="homepg">
   <a href="#secondpg" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-icon-mail ui-btn-icon-top universalfont" data-transition="none">Page2</a>
   </div>
   <div data-role="page" id="secondpg" data-url="secondpg">
     <div id="divhistory">
     <ul>
        <li><img src="http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/YBgYGD5KnpPdzqJRSJEJ_YxmH-kPi1PzZ5qbVR9thAImUlvyNPjSaEjBJTLPiQF4I9ydYMLmUDyjiKM7ZttiaUEPuEB37ULYESOTQxc"></li>
        <li><img src="http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/YBgYGD5KnpPdzqJRSJEJ_YxmH-kPi1PzZ5qbVR9thAImUlvyNPjSaEjBJTLPiQF4I9ydYMLmUDyjiKM7ZttiaUEPuEB37ULYESOTQxc"></li>
        <li><img src="http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/YBgYGD5KnpPdzqJRSJEJ_YxmH-kPi1PzZ5qbVR9thAImUlvyNPjSaEjBJTLPiQF4I9ydYMLmUDyjiKM7ZttiaUEPuEB37ULYESOTQxc"></li>
        <li><img src="http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/YBgYGD5KnpPdzqJRSJEJ_YxmH-kPi1PzZ5qbVR9thAImUlvyNPjSaEjBJTLPiQF4I9ydYMLmUDyjiKM7ZttiaUEPuEB37ULYESOTQxc"></li>
        <li><img src="http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/YBgYGD5KnpPdzqJRSJEJ_YxmH-kPi1PzZ5qbVR9thAImUlvyNPjSaEjBJTLPiQF4I9ydYMLmUDyjiKM7ZttiaUEPuEB37ULYESOTQxc"></li>
        <li><img src="http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/YBgYGD5KnpPdzqJRSJEJ_YxmH-kPi1PzZ5qbVR9thAImUlvyNPjSaEjBJTLPiQF4I9ydYMLmUDyjiKM7ZttiaUEPuEB37ULYESOTQxc"></li>
        <li><img src="http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/YBgYGD5KnpPdzqJRSJEJ_YxmH-kPi1PzZ5qbVR9thAImUlvyNPjSaEjBJTLPiQF4I9ydYMLmUDyjiKM7ZttiaUEPuEB37ULYESOTQxc"></li>
     </ul>
     </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I solve this? Thanks

Comment: Do you have more code? or a JSFiddle? I would like to know what pagecreate does.

Comment: @BonifatiusK, you can refer from here, http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/event_pagecreate.asp